# How to pass gitlab-ci secrets via docker-compose to spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have a `cicd` pipeline in `gitlab` that uses gitlab-secrets to publish them to a `spring-boot` application as follows:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my-app:
    image: my-app-image:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test
      - app.welcome.secret=$APP_WELCOME_SECRET
```

Of course I defined the `$APP_WELCOME_SECRET` as variable it gitlabs ci/cd variables configuration page.

Problem: running the gitlab-ci pipelines results in:

`The APP_WELCOME_SECRET variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

But why?

Comment: you can solve this using a command in a script step in gitlab-cli... like this sed -i "s|$APP_WELCOME_SECRET|app.welcome.secret=xxx|g" docker-compose.yml, but your variable APP_WELCOME_ME must contain same value "app.welcome.secret=myvaluefromgitlab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by writing the secret value into a `.env` file as follows:

`gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - touch .env
    - echo "APP_WELCOME_SECRET=$APP_WELCOME_SECRET" >> .env
    - scp -i $SSH_KEY docker-compose.yml .env user@$MY_SERVER:~/deployment/app
```

While that works, I would still be interested in a better approach.